# WSO2AM - How can I set the redirect_uri to schemes other than http/https in the store?

Tags: android, ios, wso2, wso2-api-manager

How can developers add schemes other than http or https in the redirect_uri in the WSO2 API Manager Store? This will help with mobile apps (iOS and Android). As an example they might want something like this as a redirect_uri "mobile://Application/callback"

Are there other solutions?

Comment: what happen if you add above url? Is store giving error? I guess it may something we have to  implement.

Comment: If you save the redirect_uri as "mobile://test" in the store, it then shows up as "Not Specified". If I go look at the Service Provider for the app in the carbon admin area the change is there. So it looks like it will work but the developer doesn't know that the change worked.

Comment: if that so please create a jira for track it